# Why does the response from telegrams come with unicode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

## Ex:

```py
r = requests.post(config['send_photo_method'], data={'chat_id':config['chat_id'], 'caption': msg_to_send}, files={"photo":get_media_blob(driver, get_img_blob(driver))})
print(r.text)
```

## Output:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":424,"from":{"id":710795082,"is_bot":true,"first_name":
                     "\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0438\u0437
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: Are you looking to convert the response from Unicode, or to get the dictionary to have differently-formatted values?

Comment: @battr yes im looking to convert the response from unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `python3.x` (assuming you've written `print()` instead of `print`), get response content with `r.json()` instead of `r.text`.